# Why does this interface have to be explicitly implemented?

Tags: c#, interface

Coming back to C# after a few years so I'm a little rusty.  Came across this (simplified) code and it's leaving my head scratching.

Why do you have to explicitly implement the `IDataItem.Children` property?  Doesn't the normal `Children` property satisfy the requirement?  After all, the property is used directly to satisfy it. Why is it not implicit?

```
public interface IDataItem {

    IEnumerable<string> Children { get; }
}

public class DataItem : IDataItem {

    public Collection<string> Children { get; } = new Collection<string>();

    // Why doesn't 'Children' above implement this automatically?!
    // After all it's used directly to satisfy the requirement!
    IEnumerable<string> IDataItem.Children => Children;
}
```

According to the C# source, here's the definition of `Collection<T>`:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false)]
public class Collection<T> :
    System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>,
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>, <-- Right Here
    System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>,
    System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<T>,
    System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<T>,
    System.Collections.IList
```

As you can see, it explicitly implements `IEnumerable<T>` and from my understanding, if 'X' implements 'Y' then 'X' *is* a 'Y', so `Collection<String>` *is* an `IEnumerable<String>` so I'm not sure why it isn't satisfied.

Comment: It's not used "directly", there's an implicit conversion (upcast) which the compiler will turn into a non-zero amount of code.

Comment: `Doesn't the normal Children property satisfy the requirement?` - No. Based on my understanding, the implementation must exactly match the interface signature including the return type.

Comment: C# does no support return type covariance.

Comment: You don't have to use `IDataItem.Children` explicitly, `public IEnumerable<string> Children => new Collection<string>();` is good enough.

Comment: @Guy: But then he has no way to use the Collection object as a Collection from inside the class :(

Comment: But now you've changed the return type of the actual property, which isn't what I want to do.  I'm saying that `Collection<String>` already implements `IEnumerable<String>` so it should be handled.

Comment: Damien, if you can a) put that in an answer, with b) the excerpt from it explaining the above, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: It isn't satisfied because as far as I can tell the spec says the types don't need to be compatible but identical: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#interface-mapping

Comment: But if 'A' implements 'B' then 'A' *is* a 'B', or so I thought.  I'm going to do a test to see if there's a difference between a subclass vs. an interface. Maybe the former will work where the latter won't.  Not sure. I'll have to test.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this example makes it clearer. We want signatures to match *exactly*<sup>1,2</sup>, no substitutions allowed, despite any inheritance relationships between the types.

We're not allowed to write this:

```
public interface IDataItem {

    void DoStuff(string value);
}

public class DataItem : IDataItem {

    public void DoStuff(object value) { }
}
```

Your example is the same, except your asking for return types rather than parameters (and employing a narrowing rather than widening conversion, for obvious reasons). Nontheless, the same principal applies. When it comes to matching signatures, the types must match *exactly*<sup>3</sup>.

You can ask for a language that would allow such things to happen and such languages may exist. But the fact of the matter is, these are the rules of C#.

---

<sup>1</sup>Outside of some limited support for [Co- and Contra-variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) involving *generics* and interfaces/delgates.

<sup>2</sup>Some may argue about whether signature is the right word to use here since *in this case*, return types matter as much as parameter types, generic arity, etc; In most other situations where someone talks about C# method signatures, they'll be explicitly ignoring the return type because they're (explicitly or implicitly) considering what the *overloading* rules say, and for overloading, return types are not part of the signature.

Nonetheless, I'm happy with my usage of the word "signature" here. Signatures aren't formally defined in the C# specification and where it's used, it's often to point out which parts of the signature *aren't* to be considered for overloading.

<sup>3</sup>Not to mention the issues that would be raised if your `Children` method was returning a `struct` that happened to implement `IEnumerable<string>`. Now you've got a method that returns the value of a value type and a caller (via the `IDataItem` interface who is expecting to receive a *reference* to an object.

So it's not even that the method could be used as-is. We'd have to (in this case) have *hidden* boxing conversions to implement the interface. When this part of C# was specced, they were, I believe, trying not to have too much "hidden magic" for code you could easily write yourself.

Comment: Who is "We"? I understand you are saying "That is the way it is" and you are right. I think the OP is really asking "why aren't contra-variant return types on interface implementations allowed?" The answer, "they just aren't" misses the point although it is factually correct. Myself, I can only speculate on why the language wasn't created this way.

Comment: @Jodrell - that's the general problem with a *lot* of `Why` questions. The best I can do is to point out that this isn't some accidental emergent property but something that really is baked into the language.

Comment: It's not quite the same.  My question is about the class satisfying a getter in the interface from within. `Collection<string>` *is* an `IEnumerable<string>` therefore everywhere that takes the interface and expects an `IEnumerable<string>` *can always* be satisfied with `Collection<string>`. Your example isn't a getter, but a setter (technically a method with a parameter), meaning it's handed an 'object' externally, and there's no guarantee what it's handed is a string so it can't satisfy the interface. I agree what you posted shouldn't work for that reason, but again, it's not the same.

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe - I'd hoped I'd already made clear in the paragraph below the code sample and in footnote 3 that the *exact same arguments* apply to return types as to parameter types.

Comment: But it's not a logic limitation. It's a compiler one.  Swift for instance handles this just fine.  You can even use a getter/setter property to satisfy a getter-only interface (i.e. a protocol in Swift parlance.)  This is because on one hand you're the one giving something to someone else whereas on the other, someone else is giving something to you based on some condition.  You have complete control over the former, but not the latter.  The former is 100% predictable and 'known' and if it's known to satisfy it, the compiler really should allow it. I get that it doesn't. It's just frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

In your example your "normal" Children property do not actually satisfy the interface requirement. The type is different. It does not really matter that you can cast it - they are different.

Similar example and maybe a bit more obvious is if you would implement an interface with a actual method that returns IEnumerable and tried an ICollection method from the actual class. There is still that compile time error.

As @Ben Voigt said the conversion still generates some code, and if you want to have it - you need to add it implicitly.

Comment: But doesn't `Collection<String>` directly implement `IEnumerable<String>`, therefore it should satisfy the requirement?  Of course the answer is 'No, it doesn't!' but can you give an example of where this would not be a good thing to do implicitly?  What's the down-side?

Comment: And one can make the argument 'If 'X' implements 'Y' then for all intents and purposes, 'X' *is* a 'Y'!' ergo I still feel this should be implicitly picked up.

Comment: @MarqueIV: Well, it would be possible for the compiler to automatically generate both versions, one returning `IEnumerable` to satisfy the interface, and one returning `Collection` to match your declared signature.  C++ does this, that's why we say it supports return-type covariance.  .NET chooses not to, maybe because the extra trickery would become visible through reflection and royally confuse people trying to use dynamic binding (which C++ doesn't have to worry about).

Comment: But, and correct me if I'm wrong, the return type *is* an `IEnumerable<string>` because `Collection<string>` implements it directly. It's not implicit.  I thought covariance was something different.

Comment: The compiler could do this but it doesn't, the question is why. Without an authoritative source we can only speculate. We need someone from the design team, who kept a good diary, to chip in and answer. The answer is probably either, "we thought it would make things too hard to understand" or "it was difficult and we didn't think it was worth the effort" or some combination of the two.

Comment: Just revisiting this. Remember, this is explicitly referring to a getter.  The compiler *doesn't* need to export both cases, only the one because `Collection<string>` *is* an `IEnumerable<string>`.  There's nothing 'extra' for the compiler to emit. Again, look at my code. There's no cast. There is never a case where a getter of type`Collection<string>` could not satisfy a getter of `IEnumerable<string>`.  That of course isn't true for setters. That makes sense as a setter in an interface expecting any `IEnumerable<string>` can't be satisfied by a setter that only takes `Collection<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered here (you have to match the interface types) and we can demonstrate the problem with an example.  If this worked:

```
public interface IDataItem {

    IEnumerable<string> Children { get; set; }

    void Wipe();
}

public class DataItem : IDataItem {

    public Collection<string> Children { get; } = new Collection<string>(); 

    public void Wipe() {
        Children.ClearItems();  //Property exists on Collection, but not on IEnumerable
    }
}
```

And we then use this code like this:

```
IDataItem x = new DataItem();

//Should be legal, as Queue implements IEnumerable. Note entirely sure
//how this would work, but this is the system you are asking about.
x.Children = new Queue<string>();

x.Wipe();  // Will fail, as Queue does not have a ClearItems method within
```

Either you mean the property to only ever be enumerable, or you need the properties of the Collection class - type your interface appropriately.

Comment: `x.Children = new Queue<string>();` would need `Children` to have a setter.

Comment: Exactly. And if you implemented a setter, you couldn't use Collection as the backing store as there's no guarantee, as you pointed out, that the type would have a ClearItems property.  But in this case, there is no setter, thus the type can only be Collection, therefore it should implement it implicitly IMHO.

Comment: There would be, I imagine, quite a bit of work within the compiler to allow this to work properly 100% of the time.  If still think that if you want your object to expose something other than the interface properties, then you are possibly using it wrong.

Comment: Can't say I agree with that last statement.  Just because something implements an interface doesn't mean that's the only thing it is.  Conversely just because something *can* fulfill an interface doesn't mean the interface owns it.  Children is a property of the class, first.  The fact it also is used for that interface is just a happy coincidence because even if you remove that interface requirement, Children is still applicable.  (Remember, this is simplified code to illustrate the question.)

Answer (score -1):

Any class that implements the interface must contain the definition for method that matches the signature that the interface specifies. The interface defines only the signature. In that way, an interface in C# is similar to an abstract class in which all the methods are abstract.

Interfaces can contain methods, properties, events, indexers, or any combination of those four member types.

Here is the good read about interfaces.
[Interfaces in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/)

Hope it will help you in further understanding.

Comment: The question wasn't what an interface is.  It was that Collection<String> already implements IEnumerable<String> (or so I thought) which AFAIT, meant it would be implicitly picked up by IDataItem, but it wasn't.  Make sense?